# how to make Login Page in asp?

Tags: asp.net

***does anyone can help me to make Login and registration page in asp
please I need it with the tiny details***

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [MSDN documentation regarding the Login control.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d51ttbhx(VS.85).aspx)